# Use ogr2ogr to filter GeoPackage by geometry type

Tags: geometry, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I have a GeoPackage that has features of different geometry types (Point & Polygon, see below) on the same layer. How can I filter all polygons from the file and create a new GeoPackage using `ogr2ogr`?

[image: screenshot of QGIS vector layers add dialogue]

Answer (score 3):

*Credits go to my colleague Elias Wanko.*

It is possible using an SQL query:

```
ogr2ogr polygons.gpkg input.gpkg -sql "SELECT * FROM input WHERE GeometryType(geometry) LIKE 'Polygon'"
```

The resulting GeoPackage has a layer called `SELECT` that contains only polygons.